# How to write data to a file like a virtual keyboard

Tags: java, linux, virtual-keyboard

I am trying to make a java program in linux which receives data from external device and print the data to the file(focused by mouse). It works like virtual keyboard which write data to any file. How it can be done?

Comment: 1) Read data from external device.  2) Write data to a file.

Comment: I don't want to write data to specific file. I want to make it like virtual keyboard which write data to any file according to the position of cursor